# Returns rvalue reference when possible, or just the decayed type when not possible

Tags: c++

I want to develop a dereference function for optional

When I give an lvalue reference to the function, I want the return type to be an lvalue reference. (i.e `int&`)

When I give a temporary object (i.e a prvalue) to the function, I want the return type to be  the decayed type (i.e `int`)

When I give a moved object (i.e a xvalue) to the function, I want the return type to be an rvalue reference (i.e `int&&`)

I wrote 2 functions :

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) bad(T &&t) {
    return *fwd(t);   
}
```

This function returns an rvalue reference when we give a prvalue, and so, we get a dangling reference

```
struct remove_rvalue_reference {
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference<T &> {
    using type = T &;
};

template <typename T>
using remove_rvalue_reference_t = typename remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;

template<typename T>
auto good(T &&t) -> remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(*fwd(t))> {
    return *fwd(t);
}
```

This function works well, but when we give a xvalue, we get the decayed type, but we want the rvalue reference

Here is a sample code

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#define fwd(x) ::std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)

template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference {
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct remove_rvalue_reference<T &> {
    using type = T &;
};

template <typename T>
using remove_rvalue_reference_t = typename remove_rvalue_reference<T>::type;

template<typename T>
decltype(auto) bad(T &&t) {
    return *fwd(t);   
}

template<typename T>
auto good(T &&t) -> remove_rvalue_reference_t<decltype(*fwd(t))> {
    return *fwd(t);
}

int main() {
    std::optional<int> a = 5;
    
    // both are lvalue reference
    decltype(auto) aref = bad(a); // ok
    decltype(auto) aref2 = good(a); // ok
    
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(aref)>);
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<decltype(aref2)>);
    
    decltype(auto) arvref = bad(std::move(a)); // ok
    decltype(auto) arvref2 = good(std::move(a)); // not ok : not a rvalue reference -> lose perf
    
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(arvref)>);
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<decltype(arvref2)>);
    
    decltype(auto) rvref = bad(std::make_optional(5)); // NOT OK !! DANGLING REF
    decltype(auto) rvref2 = good(std::make_optional(5)); // OK
    
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<decltype(rvref)>);
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<decltype(rvref2)>);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to distinguish prvalues from xvalue arguments.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of...